# Using the promise constructor to send back a value to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, xmlhttprequest

I am using the promise function to promisify XHR and i will like to know how to get the response, and post it back to the server if the response is successful.

I am doing something like this

```
function createChannel(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
            var hashValue = resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            console.log(hashValue);
        }
        else {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
    xhr.send(json);
});
}
createChannel(method, url)
    .then(function (datums) {
    console.log(datums)
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error('Sorry There Was An Error!', err.statusText);
});
```

if this createChannel succeed, i will like to take the hashvalue variable, and make a request to the server to get a new value.

```
.then(function (createChannel) {
    console.log(createChannel);    
});
```

is this possible using promise? 
Thank you for the advice.

Comment: It is unclear what "send it out again" means?  When you get the resolved promise and get your `datums` value in the `.then()` handler, what is it you want to do at that point?

Comment: hey @jfriend00 sorry about my choice of wordings, i will like to make a new request to the server/url when i get the resolved promise. 

I want to take the hash variable and make a new post request

Comment: OK, I showed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `.then()` handler, you just issue a new request and return that promise, chaining it to the first:

```
createChannel(method, url).then(function (datums) {
    console.log(datums);
    // call some other async function here that returns a promise
    return someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(datums);
}).then(function(finalResult) {
    console.log(finalResult);        
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error('Sorry There Was An Error!', err.statusText);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems this was were i was getting confused, I will try this out and see if it works.

Comment: Hello @jfriend00, i want to know, does createchannel already holds the value of the hashvalue variable? 
I don't know if i am asking a stupid question that i should already know. Thanks for the help

Comment: i figured it out, Thank you.

Comment: @PythonRookie - In your code, the parameter `datums` will be the result of `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`.  Your `hashValue` variable inside your xhr function is meaningless because `resolve()` does not have a return value.